# keras_nlp.metrics.Bleu ValueError: y_pred must be of rank 0, 1 or 2. Found rank: 3

Tags: keras, nlp, machine-translation, bleu

I am currently engaged in the process of fine-tuning the google/mT5-small model on Google Colab for a translation task. To assess the quality of translations, I am utilizing the keras_nlp.metrics.Bleu metric to compute the Bleu score. However, I have encountered an error:

```
ValueError: y_pred must be of rank 0, 1 or 2. Found rank: 3
```

I attempted to search for the solution to this issue on Google, but regrettably, I was unable to obtain a resolution.

Here is the details of the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-3c7a368af456> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 ]
      9 
---> 10 model.fit(x=tf_train_set, validation_data=tf_val_set, epochs=5, callbacks=callbacks)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     59     def error_handler(*args, **kwargs):
     60         if not tf.debugging.is_traceback_filtering_enabled():
---> 61             return fn(*args, **kwargs)
     62 
     63         filtered_tb = None

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1740                         ):
   1741                             callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1742                             tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1743                             if data_handler.should_sync:
   1744                                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    139     try:
    140       if not is_traceback_filtering_enabled():
--> 141         return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    142     except NameError:
    143       # In some very rare cases,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    823 
    824       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 825         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    826 
    827       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    871       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    872       initializers = []
--> 873       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    874     finally:
    875       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    692     # Force the definition of the function for these arguments
    693     self._concrete_variable_creation_fn = (
--> 694         self._variable_creation_fn    # pylint: disable=protected-access
    695         ._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
    696             *args, **kwds))

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
    174     """Returns a concrete function which cleans up its graph function."""
    175     with self._lock:
--> 176       concrete_function, _ = self._maybe_define_concrete_function(args, kwargs)
    177     return concrete_function
    178 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py in _maybe_define_concrete_function(self, args, kwargs)
    169       kwargs = {}
    170 
--> 171     return self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
    172 
    173   def _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
    396           kwargs = placeholder_bound_args.kwargs
    397 
--> 398           concrete_function = self._create_concrete_function(
    399               args, kwargs, func_graph)
    400 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py in _create_concrete_function(self, args, kwargs, func_graph)
    303 
    304     concrete_function = monomorphic_function.ConcreteFunction(
--> 305         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
    306             self._name,
    307             self._python_function,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, create_placeholders)
   1053 
   1054     _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
-> 1055     func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1056 
   1057     # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    595         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    596         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 597           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    598         return out
    599 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/autograph_util.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     50     except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
     51       if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
---> 52         raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
     53       else:
     54         raise

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/autograph_util.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     39     """Calls a converted version of original_func."""
     40     try:
---> 41       return api.converted_call(
     42           original_func,
     43           args,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
    437     try:
    438       if kwargs is not None:
--> 439         result = converted_f(*effective_args, **kwargs)
    440       else:
    441         result = converted_f(*effective_args)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
    375 
    376   if not options.user_requested and conversion.is_allowlisted(f):
--> 377     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
    378 
    379   # internal_convert_user_code is for example turned off when issuing a dynamic

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, update_cache)
    458   if kwargs is not None:
    459     return f(*args, **kwargs)
--> 460   return f(*args)
    461 
    462 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in step_function(model, iterator)
   1320                 )
   1321             data = next(iterator)
-> 1322             outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
   1323             outputs = reduce_per_replica(
   1324                 outputs,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in run(***failed resolving arguments***)
   1671       fn = autograph.tf_convert(
   1672           fn, autograph_ctx.control_status_ctx(), convert_by_default=False)
-> 1673       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1674 
   1675   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   3248       kwargs = {}
   3249     with self._container_strategy().scope():
-> 3250       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
   3251 
   3252   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   4046   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):
   4047     with ReplicaContext(self._container_strategy(), replica_id_in_sync_group=0):
-> 4048       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   4049 
   4050   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations, options):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    691       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    692         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 693           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    694         else:
    695           raise

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    688       try:
    689         with conversion_ctx:
--> 690           return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
    691       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    692         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
    375 
    376   if not options.user_requested and conversion.is_allowlisted(f):
--> 377     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
    378 
    379   # internal_convert_user_code is for example turned off when issuing a dynamic

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, update_cache)
    457 
    458   if kwargs is not None:
--> 459     return f(*args, **kwargs)
    460   return f(*args)
    461 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in run_step(data)
   1301 
   1302             def run_step(data):
-> 1303                 outputs = model.train_step(data)
   1304                 # Ensure counter is updated only if `train_step` succeeds.
   1305                 with tf.control_dependencies(_minimum_control_deps(outputs)):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py in train_step(self, data)
   1679         self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
   1680 
-> 1681         self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
   1682         # Collect metrics to return
   1683         return_metrics = {}

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/compile_utils.py in update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    603                 if metric_obj is None:
    604                     continue
--> 605                 metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    606 
    607             for weighted_metric_obj in weighted_metric_objs:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/metrics_utils.py in decorated(metric_obj, *args, **kwargs)
     75 
     76         with tf_utils.graph_context_for_symbolic_tensors(*args, **kwargs):
---> 77             update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     78         if update_op is not None:  # update_op will be None in eager execution.
     79             metric_obj.add_update(update_op)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/metrics/base_metric.py in update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    138                     obj_update_state, control_status
    139                 )
--> 140                 return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    141 
    142         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    691       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    692         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 693           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    694         else:
    695           raise

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    688       try:
    689         with conversion_ctx:
--> 690           return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
    691       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    692         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
    437     try:
    438       if kwargs is not None:
--> 439         result = converted_f(*effective_args, **kwargs)
    440       else:
    441         result = converted_f(*effective_args)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_nlp/src/metrics/bleu.py in tf__update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    104                         return fscope_1.ret(retval__1, do_return_1)
    105                 y_true = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(validate_and_fix_rank), (ag__.ld(y_true), 'y_true', 1), None, fscope)
--> 106                 y_pred = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(validate_and_fix_rank), (ag__.ld(y_pred), 'y_pred', 0), None, fscope)
    107                 y_true = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self)._tokenizer, (ag__.ld(y_true),), None, fscope)
    108                 y_pred = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self)._tokenizer, (ag__.ld(y_pred),), None, fscope)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
    329   if conversion.is_in_allowlist_cache(f, options):
    330     logging.log(2, 'Allowlisted %s: from cache', f)
--> 331     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, False)
    332 
    333   if ag_ctx.control_status_ctx().status == ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, update_cache)
    458   if kwargs is not None:
    459     return f(*args, **kwargs)
--> 460   return f(*args)
    461 
    462 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_nlp/src/metrics/bleu.py in validate_and_fix_rank(inputs, tensor_name, base_rank)
    101                                 ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank == ag__.ld(base_rank) + 2, if_body_2, else_body_2, get_state_2, set_state_2, ('do_return_1', 'retval__1'), 2)
    102                             ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank == ag__.ld(base_rank) + 1, if_body_3, else_body_3, get_state_3, set_state_3, ('do_return_1', 'retval__1'), 2)
--> 103                         ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank == ag__.ld(base_rank), if_body_4, else_body_4, get_state_4, set_state_4, ('do_return_1', 'retval__1'), 2)
    104                         return fscope_1.ret(retval__1, do_return_1)
    105                 y_true = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(validate_and_fix_rank), (ag__.ld(y_true), 'y_true', 1), None, fscope)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py in if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, symbol_names, nouts)
   1267     _tf_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, symbol_names, nouts)
   1268   else:
-> 1269     _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)
   1270 
   1271 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py in _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)
   1320 def _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse):
   1321   """Overload of if_stmt that executes a Python if statement."""
-> 1322   return body() if cond else orelse()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_nlp/src/metrics/bleu.py in else_body_4()
    100                                     raise ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(ValueError), (f'{ag__.ld(tensor_name)} must be of rank {ag__.ld(base_rank)}, {ag__.ld(base_rank) + 1} or {ag__.ld(base_rank) + 2}. Found rank: {ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank}',), None, fscope_1)
    101                                 ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank == ag__.ld(base_rank) + 2, if_body_2, else_body_2, get_state_2, set_state_2, ('do_return_1', 'retval__1'), 2)
--> 102                             ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank == ag__.ld(base_rank) + 1, if_body_3, else_body_3, get_state_3, set_state_3, ('do_return_1', 'retval__1'), 2)
    103                         ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank == ag__.ld(base_rank), if_body_4, else_body_4, get_state_4, set_state_4, ('do_return_1', 'retval__1'), 2)
    104                         return fscope_1.ret(retval__1, do_return_1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py in if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, symbol_names, nouts)
   1267     _tf_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, symbol_names, nouts)
   1268   else:
-> 1269     _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)
   1270 
   1271 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py in _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)
   1320 def _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse):
   1321   """Overload of if_stmt that executes a Python if statement."""
-> 1322   return body() if cond else orelse()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_nlp/src/metrics/bleu.py in else_body_3()
     99                                     nonlocal do_return_1, retval__1
    100                                     raise ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(ValueError), (f'{ag__.ld(tensor_name)} must be of rank {ag__.ld(base_rank)}, {ag__.ld(base_rank) + 1} or {ag__.ld(base_rank) + 2}. Found rank: {ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank}',), None, fscope_1)
--> 101                                 ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank == ag__.ld(base_rank) + 2, if_body_2, else_body_2, get_state_2, set_state_2, ('do_return_1', 'retval__1'), 2)
    102                             ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank == ag__.ld(base_rank) + 1, if_body_3, else_body_3, get_state_3, set_state_3, ('do_return_1', 'retval__1'), 2)
    103                         ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank == ag__.ld(base_rank), if_body_4, else_body_4, get_state_4, set_state_4, ('do_return_1', 'retval__1'), 2)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py in if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, symbol_names, nouts)
   1267     _tf_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, symbol_names, nouts)
   1268   else:
-> 1269     _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)
   1270 
   1271 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py in _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)
   1320 def _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse):
   1321   """Overload of if_stmt that executes a Python if statement."""
-> 1322   return body() if cond else orelse()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_nlp/src/metrics/bleu.py in else_body_2()
     98                                 def else_body_2():
     99                                     nonlocal do_return_1, retval__1
--> 100                                     raise ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(ValueError), (f'{ag__.ld(tensor_name)} must be of rank {ag__.ld(base_rank)}, {ag__.ld(base_rank) + 1} or {ag__.ld(base_rank) + 2}. Found rank: {ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank}',), None, fscope_1)
    101                                 ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank == ag__.ld(base_rank) + 2, if_body_2, else_body_2, get_state_2, set_state_2, ('do_return_1', 'retval__1'), 2)
    102                             ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(inputs).shape.rank == ag__.ld(base_rank) + 1, if_body_3, else_body_3, get_state_3, set_state_3, ('do_return_1', 'retval__1'), 2)

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1338, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_nlp/src/metrics/bleu.py", line 342, in validate_and_fix_rank  *
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: y_pred must be of rank 0, 1 or 2. Found rank: 3
```

And my code is here:

```py
checkpoint = "google/mt5-small"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model = TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
optimizer = AdamWeightDecay(learning_rate=2e-5, weight_decay_rate=0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy", keras_nlp.metrics.Bleu(tokenizer)])

callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(f'models/{model_name}',save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True),
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=f'logs/{model_name}_logs')
]

model.fit(x=tf_train_set, validation_data=tf_val_set, epochs=5, callbacks=callbacks)
```

How to fix this problem, or is there something else can compute Bleu score?

Please help me, thanks!!ヾ(•ω•`)o